# Ogre 3D Visibility Advice

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, directx, ogre

I would like an advice about some real-time rendering optimization.
I'm rendering a BSP level, by only using the mesh, textures, entities, and lightmaps, not using VIS at all.

I'm trying to make my own Cell/Portal rendering system, a very basic one, but here is the problem, since Ogre uses a basic frustum culling (as I've heard), I think it would render everything behind the walls if every portals are in the field of view :

[image: Simple map with zones and portals in blue]

Do you have some better ideas to implement this ?

I am getting 650 FPS at a resolution of 1920x1080 if I render only zone only. I can get 1300 FPS if I see nothing.

Is 300 FPS good for a complex scene like this one?
[image]

I would like to make a lot of basic things clear for me.

Comment: What is the refresh rate of your monitor/ display?

Comment: Hello, the refresh rate is 60Hz with Nvidia NVS 5100M, but I've turned VSync off, but does it matter for old graphic cards if I get 90FPS on a complex scene ?

Comment: No it does not matter if your monitor can only refresh the screen with 60Hz. Thats only wasting GPU power. 60 FPS is a perfect frame-rate, don't worry and switch on vsync.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ogre3D actually comes with a scenemanager called PCZSM, the [Portal Connected Zone Scene Manager](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Portal+Connected+Zone+Scene+Manager), which is meant exactly for the purpose of portal-based occlusion culling. It should fit very well with your project.
My usage experience is that it's very robust, although documentation is sparse - mostly it's in the form of [forum posts](http://www.ogre3d.org/addonforums/viewforum.php?f=22).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try again with this Scene Manager then.